# Prefill current date in Google Form with Google Apps Script

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form to a spreadsheet and I need a date field pre-filled with the current date.

Something like an `"onOpen trigger"`, which updates the date field or a date field with now().

Is this possible in Google Apps Script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Record Time taken to complete a google form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942995/record-time-taken-to-complete-a-google-form)

Answer (score 3):

In your case, some of the points of using the Form remain unclear. Suppose that you have the ability to edit a link to the Form or your users agree to add the [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) to their browser.

### Common code

```
let id='1FAIpQLScx-1H1moCzBfkTEOZnVgBScbJeHZ4YE5E6IY2mNZvMuVcOXA';
window.open(
  `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/${id}/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1000000=`+
  (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]
);
```

### Bookmarklet

Just add the next string to the bookmarks bar

```
javascript:let id = '1FAIpQLScx-1H1moCzBfkTEOZnVgBScbJeHZ4YE5E6IY2mNZvMuVcOXA'; window.open(`https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/${id}/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1000000=` + (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]);
```

Comment: After spending at least 2 hours searching and creating app script, I think this is the best solution ever!

Answer (score 1):

I put a static HTML page on S3 with a few line of Javascript for redirecting.  See https://jsfiddle.net/barryku/3etd8qf0/

```
var formId = "1FAIpQLSc_acGSzp2VeJIyG0tNJwqcNdUPOweLROGenY0Fe56I635VGQ";
var dateField = "entry.1608430301";
var formsUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/"+ formId + "/viewform?usp=pp_url&" + dateField + "=$$today&entry.747437339=Yes";

var today = new Date();
var redirectUrl = formsUrl.replace("$$today", new Date(today.getTime() - (today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().split('T')[0]);
window.location.replace(redirectUrl);
```

Comment: Could you include details on how to implement this? Do you call the Javascript when the form loads or run this on another page that redirects to the form?