# Measuring item response times in google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp, google-form-quiz

I want to measure the time taken for pupils to respond to individual multiple choice questions using google forms in quiz mode.

I think one solution is to use google apps script in forms to provide a timestamp for each separate question, rather than just once on submission (this would let me subtract the timestamp for question 3 from the timestamp for question 4 to find the time taken on question 4).

Please note - I don't want to set a time limit for questions - it could take an hour and that would be fine. I just want to know how long each question took.

Can anyone suggest how I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Forms has no trigger that can listen to a response to a single item, only to [form submission](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically). It doesn't have [an edit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) either.

So there is actually no way to track the time the student takes for each question.

As a workaround, I'd recommend sending a separate form for each question, even though knowing the time taken for each student to respond to the form is not easy either, because [an onOpen trigger only occurs when an editor opens the form to modify it, not when a user opens it to respond](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), so you cannot know when the student opened the form.

So, an option would be to first send a form with instructions and a link to the form first question.

Then, to know when the student opened the form, an option would be to send two connected forms, one for instructions, etc. Similarly to [the workaround proposed for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942995/record-time-taken-to-complete-a-google-form), in the confirmation message of this first form, add the link of the second form (the first one with a question). In the confirmation message of the second form, add the link of the third, and so on.

Each of the forms should have an [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) that will get a timestamp for the submission of each form. By subtracting each timestamp to the previous one you would get the time taken for each question.

===============

A different workaround would be to create a [DurationItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/duration-item) or a [DateTimeItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/date-time-item) for each question in the form, so that users themselves indicate the time it took for them to answer to each question. But for obvious, I guess this is not a workable option.